# MYSQL proper way to index calulated where conditions ( where myTable.a > myTable.b)

Tags: mysql, indexing, laravel-5.3

MySQL --version is 5.7.18

What would be the proper way to optimize a query like:

```
select id,name from mytable where a - b > 0
```

where mytable is something like

- `id` - primary key,increments, big integer
- `name` - varchar(255)
- `a` - integer, unsigned, 10
- `b` - integer, unsigned, 10

Would adding indexes to `a` and `b` columns help? Should I just add a third column `a_minus_b`, index it, and then just be careful to update it properly every time or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generated column and then an index on that:

```
alter table mytable add column abdiff int generated always as (a - b);

create index idx_mytable_abdiff on mytable(abdiff);
```

Note:  This uses an `int` for the type.  You can specify whatever type you like for the difference.

Comment: This sounds great and simple. Will the generated column reflect the old data in the table?

Comment: @dbr . . . A generated column is calculated when it is used.  An index on a generated column is smart enough to update when any of the columns in the generated expression change.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit of a newbie here. Dis assumed it but wanted to check just in case. Will accept when I alter my db and test.

Comment: @dbr . . . This is very new functionality in MySQL.